# Python Ecotect Geco Scripting "Unscriptable"

Tags: python, grasshopper

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import scriptcontext
import Rhino

if ACTIVE:

    for i in range(len(GEO)):

        scriptcontext.doc = ghdoc

        GEO_id = GEO[i]

        doc_object = rs.coercerhinoobject(GEO_id)

        attributes = doc_object.Attributes
        geometry = doc_object.Geometry

        scriptcontext.doc = Rhino.RhinoDoc.ActiveDoc

        rhino_obj = scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Add(geometry, attributes)

        rs.ObjectColor(rhino_obj, color[i])

        mat_id = rs.AddMaterialToObject(rhino_obj)
        rs.MaterialColor(mat_id, color[i])
```

> "Runtime error (TypeErrorException): 'Color' object is unsubscriptable
>   Traceback:
>     line 23, in script"

I have no idea why the "ObjectColor" is unscriptable, I have matched it with the python API so many times. AM I not seeing something that I should?

Comment: Which line is line 23? In any case, the error is that the `Color` object is un-**subscript**-able, not un-**script**-able.

Comment: rs.ObjectColor(rhino_obj, color[i]) is line 23,

Ohkay, so is the "subscript" the (rhino_obj, colour [i]) part?

Comment: Specifically, subscripting is the use of the square brackets `[]`, which is in this case at `color[i]`. Whatever the type of `color` is, it doesn't support using `[]` for subscripting.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! I solved it, yes you were right. I changed the "color" into a list item on Grasshopper and it worked. Thanks man :)

Comment: can I make it show you answered the question of anything?